# AVX512: Best way to unpack Words into Double Words and pack back?

Tags: intrinsics, avx512

I'm got lost with shuffling on AVX512, please help me.

What I need is to unpack __m512i register contains 32 Words into two __m512i registers contains 16 Double Words each, but the words from source should be placed sequentially to the destinations (first 16 Words into 1st reg and next 16 Elements into the second).

Pretty simple code:

```c
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned short int Src[32], Dst[32];
    int DstHi[16], DstLo[16]; //later will be aligned to 64 byte boundary

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) Src[i] = i;

    __m512i src = _mm512_loadu_si512((__m512i*)Src); //32 Source pixels
    __m512i dst_lo = _mm512_unpacklo_epi16(src, _mm512_set1_epi16(0));
    __m512i dst_hi = _mm512_unpackhi_epi16(src, _mm512_set1_epi16(0));
    //do something
    __m512i dst = _mm512_packus_epi32(dst_lo, dst_hi);
    _mm512_storeu_si512((__m512i*)Dst, dst);
    //Test:
    _mm512_storeu_si512((__m512i*)DstHi, dst_lo);
    _mm512_storeu_si512((__m512i*)DstLo, dst_hi);
    printf("\nDstLo (_mm512_unpacklo_epi16):");
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%d,", DstLo[i]);
    printf("\nDstHi (_mm512_unpackhi_epi16):");
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%d,", DstHi[i]);

    printf("\nDst packed back:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) printf("%d;", Dst[i]);
}
```

will give me

```
DstLo (_mm512_unpacklo_epi16): 4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15,20,21,22,23,28,29,30,31,
DstHi (_mm512_unpackhi_epi16): 0,1,2,3,8,9,10,11,16,17,18,19,24,25,26,27,
Dst packed back:
0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;
```

But what I need is DstLo: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 and DstHi:16,17,18,19,20,...31

I was able to do this with AVX2/__m256i using _mm256_permute2x128_si256 and _mm256_permute4x64_epi64 with appropriate flags, but unable to realize the same in AVX512/__m512i. Tried permutation and shuffling, got anything, but not what I need. Any elegant idea how to achieve my goal? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your (actual) source a register or memory? Do you want to sign-extend or zero-extend the input?

Comment: Unpacking odd / even narrow elements is usually efficient, like AND and shift to unpack, then shift and blend to re-pack.  (Or a merge-masked shift?).  Otherwise probably `vpmovzxwd` (or sxwd` for sign-extension) for the low 256, and a shuffle for the high 256.  And `vpermt2w` for repacking I guess, or `vpackssdw` / `vpermd`.  (256 and 512-bit versions of SSE instructions like `punpcklwd` / `packssdw` operate in-lane, a separate 128-bit unpack / pack operation in each 128-bit lane of a YMM or ZMM vector. This sucks a lot, so it's good that AVX-512 at least provides new lane-crossing shuffles.)

Comment: chtz, the source is the memory and I would like to get zero-extend. Technically this is the 16 bit image (where 12 bit only used), and I tried to perform flat field correction (subtract dark image, then multiply by flat field). The flat field image is 32bit integer prepared for integer arithmetic to avoid float point multiplication.

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter for pointing me to these functions, I'll learn! For the moment I was able to prepare input data (which is flat image for flat field correction) with "pre-shuffling" by reordering values outside of time-critical loop, so as result I don't need to reorder data any longer, and it works. Not very elegant, but probably fastest way.

Comment: If the source is from memory, you should (usually) just load one half and convert it to the desired type, e.g., `dst_lo = _mm512_cvtepu16_epi32(_mm256_loadu_epi16(Src)); dst_hi = _mm512_cvtepu16_epi32(_mm256_loadu_epi16(Src+16));` The compiler should use a `vpmovzxwd` with memory source (with optimizations enabled): https://godbolt.org/z/4brnqnP7K